# unable to pass multiple listbox items to php

Tags: php, html, listbox

i need to store multiple elements of listbox item into the database , but i am unable to pass the elements from the html form to php. Please help

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Save.php">
    <select name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Holland">Holland</option>
        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

    <?php

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    $con = $_POST['country'];
    foreach($con as $selected)
    {
    echo 'selected'.$selected;

    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code shall solve your issue

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit']))
{

    if (isset($_POST['country'])){
        $con = $_POST['country'];
        foreach($con as $selected)
            echo 'selected'.$selected;
    }
}
?>

<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="Save.php">
    <select name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Holland">Holland</option>
        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: its not showing any error but still i am not able to print the elements

Comment: You need to select the value inside the list, so that it will display you the result. No selection will have the empty POST['country'] value.

Answer (score 0):

```
//the post request takes the Tag NAMES only
<input type="Submit" value="Submit" name="submit"/>
```

[see this phpfiddle it is working fine only](http://www.phpfiddle.org/main/code/2ta-ngc)

Comment: If the name is an array, it will get all values from a multi-select.

Comment: yes he missed the 'name=submit' so the if condition is returning false

Comment: Ah, gotcha. I thought you were talking about the multiple select.

Comment: did it but its throwing error as foolowing:

Comment: its showing:   Notice: Undefined index: country in C:\wamp\www\Project_1\Save.php on line 4

Comment: `print_r($_POST);` is your friend. It doesn't look like you should receive that notice from the code you have.

Comment: exactlly i feel the same but it is showing and its driving me nuts.

Comment: do you still have the problem?

Comment: see the phpfiddle link in my answer,you can get some idea,all the best

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a `POST` index of `submit` hence your `isset()` is failing.  You are also missing a closing brace for your `if` statement in your code example.  I've modified your example to use the `$_POST['country']` for the `isset()`.  This bit worked for me as far as returning selected values goes:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
    <select name="country[]" multiple="multiple">
        <option value="Belgium">Belgium</option>
        <option value="France">France</option>
        <option value="Germany">Germany</option>
        <option value="Holland">Holland</option>
        <option value="Greece">Greece</option>
    </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>

<?php

    if(isset($_POST['country']))
    {
        $con = $_POST['country'];
        foreach($con as $selected)
        {
            echo 'selected'.$selected;
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: its not showing any error anymore but still i am unable to echo the listbox elements.

Comment: Are you passing the form submission back into the same page where this test code is running?  When I run the code, plus a call to `print_r($_POST['country']` I get the output of `selectedFranceselectedGermanyArray ( [0] => France [1] => Germany )` in my browser window.

Comment: yes, html and php code are in the same page.

Comment: Hmmm...odd.  Like I said, I get code output from what I have above, so what you see there is doing the job of getting at the countries I select in the list.